# How to position some columns in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have issue with positioning some text in a table.

I have two columns that have `colspan="4"` - these are `first column` and `second column`:

It should looks like this:

```
first column   second column
some text      Value   Currency
                 100   USD
                3000   USD
```

But as I've done it, it looks like that:

```
first column   second column
some text             Value  Currency
                        100  USD
                       3000  USD
                      12000  USD
                        400  USD
```

Here is my real code:

```
 <tr>
   <td colspan="4">
     First column
  </td>
   <td colspan="4">
     Second column
  </td>
</tr>
     <tr class="empty"><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
           <?php echo 'Price';?>:
        </td>

        <td colspan='1' style="text-align: right">
            <?php echo 'Value';?>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px" colspan='1' >
            <?php echo 'Currency';?>
        </td>
        <td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>    
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
       </td>
       <td colspan="1" style="text-align: right"><?php echo $price; ?></td>
       <td colspan="1" class="pull-right"><?php echo $currency; ?></td>
       <td colspan="2" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

```
.pull-right {
                padding-left: 10px;   
            }
```

Comment: `<?php echo 'Price';?>` really?

Comment: `<td colspan="1" class="pull-right"><?php echo $currency; ?>` lacks a `</td>`.

Comment: My text was bigger, there were variables and other code, so I reduced it. That's why it lookd like this: <?php echo 'Price';?>  </td> is not missing, it's when copying.

Comment: Just add a blank column, that should do the trick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/cLpka2qk/)

Comment: I want to looks like first example. I tried to make first column to be with `colspan="3"` not `colspan="4"` but in this case it's not positioned properly again - it's to the left, not below `second column`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with this code. First, you should always nest your rows within a table. Second, what you have with value and currency is supposed to be a nested table, but you are trying to reproduce that kind of layout without the proper html. Try using the following template to accomplish your goal. I have tested it and it does produce the exact layout you had asked for.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            First Column
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
            Second Column
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top;text-align: center;">
            Some Text
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Value
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Currency
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        100
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        USD
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        3000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        USD
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the result (borders added):

[image]

Comment: It's still the same. Problem is that Value is much in right, it's not under `second column` text.

Comment: I did notice some problems after, so I made an update. The template I posted should work well for you.

Comment: I just updated again after noticing a small issue with alignment. Try it out now, and I am 100% sure that this post will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `<td colspan="2" style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>` to get the desired results. And instead of using `<td colspan='1'>` on other columns, use `<td colspan='2'>` instead.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td colspan="4">
     First column
  </td>
   <td colspan="4">
     Second column
  </td>
</tr>
     <tr class="empty"><td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
           Price
        </td>

        <td colspan='2' style="text-align: right">
            Value
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px" colspan='2' >
            Currency
        </td> 
    </tr>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">Price 1</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="pull-right">Currency 1</td>
 </tr>   
 </table>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL2cry9m/1/)

PS: You don't need to print those static texts using PHP `echo`

**Change from:**

```
<td colspan="4">
  <?php echo 'Price';?>:
</td>
```

**To:**

```
<td colspan="4">
  Price:
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to force colspans on this table, it looks like it can simply be done with three td's per tr

heres how I rebuilt the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First column</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="empty">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo 'Price';?>:</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo 'Value';?></td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo 'Currency';?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:10px;">Some Text</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $price; ?></td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo $currency; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you all but nothing changes..If someone want to show him file?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I think you meant how it should look like, consider this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">First Column</td>
        <td colspan="4">Second Column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="4" style="vertical-align:top;">Some Text</td>
        <td>Value</td><td colspan="3">Currency</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td colspan="3">USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3000</td>
        <td colspan="3">USD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I don't see a sense in the `colspan="4"` on the first and second column. If you remove all the `colspan` attributes and just add `colspan="2"` to the row with "second column" it will look the same and be less complicated.